# register_activation_hook callable function not being called

Tags: wordpress

i am trying to call a callable function that will write a file when plugin is activated

this is my code

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'ordero_create');

function ordero_create(){

$file = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/errors.txt'; 
$open = fopen( $file, "a" );
```

with above code, plugin is successfully activated but ordero_create() function is not being called.

when i change register_activation_hook to become like this

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, ordero_create());
```

the plugin is successfully activated and ordero_create() function is being called. but there is a warning like this

```
The plugin generated 230 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.
```

i'm sure there is no space or new line after `?>` or before `<?php`

Comment: can you provide whole function body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, its solved.

previously i have 2 files, index.php that contain standard wordpress plugin initialization that call another php file that contain the main code

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name: tes
Plugin URI: xxx
Description: xxx
Version: 1.0.1
Author: xxx
Author URI: xxx
License: 
    Copyright 2020 xxx


Logs:
v1.0
- Release first version.
*/
include_once('tes.php');
?>
```

and then on tes.php

```
<?php
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'ordero_tb_create');



function ordero_tb_create(){

$file = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/errors.txt'; 
$open = fopen( $file, "a" ); 
}
?>
```

after i merge these two file into one its work like it should be